# Find neighborhood with given max level

Tags: python, graph-theory

I need to get all nodes that belongs to the neighborhood of selected node. For example if given level equals 1 the result for graph below should be [black, red, red, red, red], if level equals 2 [black, red, red, red, red, green, green, green, green, green, green, green, green] etc. [image]

I tried some recursion, but it works a bit like DFS and because the stop criterion was depth <= max_level it was skipping some nodes that should be included.

```py
def get_neighborhood(node, edges, neighborhood_level, depth, nodes_acc):
    neighbors_filter = np.where(edges[1] == node)
    all_neighbors    = edges[0][neighbors_filter]
    neighbors        = all_neighbors[check_if_not_in(all_neighbors, nodes_acc)]

    if depth == neighborhood_level:
        return nodes_acc

    for neighbor in neighbors:
        nodes_acc = torch.unique(torch.cat((nodes_acc, torch.Tensor([neighbor]))))
    
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        nodes_acc = torch.unique(torch.cat((nodes_acc, get_neighborhood(neighbor, edges, neighborhood_level, depth + 1, nodes_acc))))

    return nodes_acc
```

- node:

```
tensor(some_id)
```

- edges:

```
tensor([[source, source, source, ..., source, source],
        [target, target, target, ..., target, target]])
```

I would really appreciate any tip. Input data doesn't have to be torch.Tensor. It could be numpy.array or plain list as well. I can convert that later :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use the Dijkstra algorithm.  This will give you the minimum distance from a starting node to every other reachable node.  Loop over the nodes and output those with the required distance.

Comment: The Dijsktra algorithm I described in my previous comment will work for any graph.  If your graph is like the one in your example, with the nodes arranged on a grid, you can do what you need very simply by calculating the Manhattan distance between nodes ( sum the absolute differences between the x and y co-ords )

Comment: I solved that modifying BFS and tracking its depth. Works good now. Thanks!